# How do i verify that $272727...2727$ ($100$ digits) can or cannot be written as a perfect square??

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, geometric-progressions

I've been stuck on this question.

I tried writing the number as as geometric progression plus $$2((10^{100}-1)/9)+5+5.10^2+5.10^4...$$

Got stuck in there.

Comment: Division by $27$ gives you $101010\ldots 1$ ($50$ "ones") which is not divisible by $3$. Thus the number is divisible by $3^3$ but not by $3^4$, i.e. it is not a square.

Comment: @StinkingBishop division by $4$ is faster for a solution.  It only requires looking at the final two digits.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah, yes, it is $\equiv 3\pmod 4$... Could do that way too!

Comment: Decimal forms of perfect squares end with 0, 1, 4, 9, 6, and 5. Not with 7.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is $27×1010\ldots 1$ [50 $1$s]. So $1010\ldots 1$ is not divisible by $3$. So the largest power of $3$ that divides this number is $27=3^3$ i.e., the power $3$ is odd.

ETA as noted in the comments by Stinking Bishop already

Comment: While correct, it is unsatisfying since the same argument does not work say for $272727\dots 27$ where there are instead $60$ copies of $27$ rather than just $50$.  In that scenario the number is divisible by $3^4$ and not $3^5$ so this argument does not work.

Comment: @JMoravitz I answered the question as asked. That the question was phrased that way implies that it probably was hoped that the student would acknowledge that $101\ldots 1$ was not a factor of 3. Meanwhile we could go further also ask if numbers of the form $101\ldots 1$ i.e., $2k+1$ digits for some $k$, are ever a square